# Function to find odd numbers returns extra value - C Language

Tags: c, function, numbers, codeblocks

I wrote a code in C to find the odd numbers from a given interval of min and max number. The function works well when it is inside the int main() but not well when outside the program as a function.

What's more is that it also prints the incremented number outside the max number given.

This is the code...

```
#include <stdio.h>
// My Function
int odd_numbers(int x, int y) {
    for (int i = x; i <= y; ++i) {
        if (i % 2 == 1) {
            printf("%d\n",i);
        }
    }
}

// Main Program
int main(void) {
    int min_num, max_num;

    printf("Input your minimum number: ");
    scanf("%d", &min_num);
    printf("Input your maximum number: ");
    scanf("%d", &max_num);

    printf("%d",odd_numbers(min_num,max_num));
}
```

and this is the output...
[As you can see, it adds an 11 besides the 9...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSQCv.png)
How can I solve this? I've tried return 0; and it returns the value 0 but i only want to return no number except the odd numbers.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide code, that actually compiles. Besides missing `}` in `main` you should also get some compiler warning about not returning any value from `odd_numbers`. As you use that return value in your last `printf` in `main` you are invoking undefined behaviour. In your case this results in printing an "extra value". If you run your program in a debugger, you may find that the last number is printed in that last `printf` in your code: `printf("%d", odd_numbers(min_num,max_num));` If you don't want it, don't print it.

Comment: You need to learn a bit about wording. Your function `odd_numbers` does not "return the odd numbers". It *prints* odd numbers and *returns* nothing at all while you promised the caller to return an `int` value.

Comment: You have undefined behaviour because you define `int odd_numbers(…)` but don't return a value.  You then try to print the value that's (not) returned.  You should just call `odd_numbers()` in your `main()` function, not embed it in a `printf()` statement (and you should define it as `void odd_numbers(…)`).  It's generally better to use the newline at the end of a format string, not the beginning: `printf("%d\n", i);`.

Comment: Thank you @JonathanLeffler calling the function removed the extra number 11 and only printed the number inside the min and max numbers... The help was much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working code.

Notes

1. Change the return type of `odd_numbers` from int to void because you are not returning anything when the function is called.
2. Only call the function `odd_numbers`, no need to printf anything because `odd_numbers` already does the job.

```
#include <stdio.h>
// My Function
void odd_numbers(int x, int y) {
    for (int i = x; i <= y; i++) {
        if (i % 2 != 0) {
            printf("\n%d",i);
        }
    }
}

// Main Program
int main(void) {
    int min_num, max_num;

    printf("Input your minimum number: ");
    scanf("%d", &min_num);
    printf("Input your maximum number: ");
    scanf("%d", &max_num);

    odd_numbers(min_num,max_num);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the modified code.

1. you have declare function return type `int` but return nothing. `odd_numbers` made to void type. no need to return anything

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// My Function
void odd_numbers(int x, int y) 
{
    int i = 0;
    for (int i = x; i <= y; i++) 
    {
        if (i % 2 != 0) 
        {
        printf("%d\n", i);
        }
    }
}

// Main Program
int main(void) {
  int min_num, max_num;

    printf("Input your minimum number: ");
    scanf("%d", &min_num);
    printf("Input your maximum number: ");
    scanf("%d", &max_num);

    odd_numbers(min_num, max_num);
    return 0;
}
```